# how to use modal attribute in jsp include tag?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

how to use modal attribute in jsp include tag ?

```
`<jsp:include  page="/WEB-INF/fd_jsp/layouts/basketcontent.jsp" /> `
```

I want to insert a variable passed as parameter in page attribute .Something like

```
`<jsp:include  page="/WEB-INF/${templateName}/layouts/basketcontent.jsp" />`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What is the output when you tried using `${templateName}`?

Comment: In ${templateName} through java I'm switchin between fd, fd_res, ff, ff_res

Comment: So are you getting values in the `<jsp:include>` accordingly or facing any problem with that?

Comment: Page is not getting loaded. Reflecting 500error

Comment: Where are you trying to load this `jsp` page? I mean, is there any container element like `<div>` or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for your issue using `jQuery` or `javascript`, 
first is to create a `hidden` field as follows,

```
<input type="hidden" id="jspPath" value="${templateName}">
```

Use a container element let's say `<div>` to load the jsp page,

```
<div id="containerDiv"></div>
```

And finally in `<head></head>` tag or in your js file load the `jsp` file dynamically.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function{
  $('#containerDiv').load('/WEB-INF/'+$('#jspPath').val()+'/layouts/basketcontent.jsp');
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, this is completely the wrong idea.  a JSP include is a server side include which will cause the specified page to be output in the stream coming from the server.  You suggested solution is a client site DOM manipulation which is ignoring the original question.  The path specified is a file path on the server, not necessarily a page you can see from the browser.  The OP is asking for how to use a variable that exists in the server environment to control files read and included by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I made variable in the JSP and set it like this:

```
String tName = "fd_jsp";
String tPath = "/WEB-INF/"+tName+"/layouts/basketcontent.jsp";
```

Then I was able to get this to work properly:

```
<jsp:include  page="<%=tPath%>" />
```